# Filtering the data processed by the shipments grid in Sylius

Tags: php, symfony, sylius

I have a shipments grid in the back office that shows every order no matter what the payment status is. I want to display only the orders where payment_status = paid.

I found nothing in the doc and on GitHub, only filters as search engines. Plus, there is no Payment status column in the grid.

How could I access the data query for this grid and select only the paid orders ?

Here's the config file shipment.yml:

```
sylius_admin_shipment:
resource: |
    alias: sylius.shipment
    section: admin
    templates: "@SyliusAdmin\\Crud"
    only: ['index']
    grid: sylius_admin_shipment
    permission: true
    vars:
        all:
            subheader: sylius.ui.manage_shipments
        index:
            icon: truck
type: sylius.resource
```

I tried to add listeners, filters, but I don't really know how can I manage the resource (which I guess is the variable containing the data ?), I tried to track the file but I didn't find anything, nor in the doc.

I'm totally new to Sylius btw, so if anyone has a tip or a solution it would be great ! Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

The block of configuration you posted is a "resource routing", which means it's a special routing handled by Sylius to generate CRUD routing for a given resource automatically. More information about this can be found in the [documentation of the ResourceBundle about routings](https://docs.sylius.com/en/1.6/components_and_bundles/bundles/SyliusResourceBundle/routing.html).

For the list page, it uses a grid, which is specified in the configuration you posted.

What you need is to [extend and modify the configuration of the grid](https://docs.sylius.com/en/1.6/customization/grid.html).
You can find  the base configuration for [this grid here](https://github.com/Sylius/Sylius/blob/master/src/Sylius/Bundle/AdminBundle/Resources/config/grids/shipment.yml).

For your case, the simplest way would be to override the method used to "select" the payments.

```
repository:
    method: createListQueryBuilder # <== Change this one
```

Then extend the `Repository` for the `Payment` resource and create your new function in it which will just add the correct `where` to the query builder used by the grid.

More information about extending the repository [can be found here](https://docs.sylius.com/en/1.6/customization/repository.html).

Hope this helps :)

Comment: That's really helpful thank you ! I'm going to try that right away :)